# Squared Multiple Correlation (SMC) of my correlation matrix tend towards 1. How to interpret this?

Tags: r, factor-analysis, matrix-inverse, parallel-analysis

In order to be able to conduct exploratory factor analysis, I want to carry out parallel analysis to determine the number of factors to be extracted. To do so, I want to extract the eignevalues of the reduced correaltion matrix. To get the reduced correlation matrix, I want to replace the diagonals of the initial correlation matrix with the squared multiple correlation (SMC) of each variable with all other variables in the matrix. My correlation matrix is of dimensions $36 \times 36$. To carry out the steps I want to use the command `smc` given by the `psych` package in `R`.

To my dismay, I found out that all 36 SMC's are equal to 1. This may be explained by the fact that the diagonal elements of the inverse of my initial correlation matrix are rather large (see entries in the column on the far left in the table below). Interestingly, if I now I reduce the number of the variables in the correlation matrix slowly (e.g. to 35, 34, etc) then the dimensions of the new correlation matrix decrease accordingly. Moreover, the diagonals of the inverses of these new marices also decrease. As the 2 columns on the right in the table below show, they decrease substantially if the matrix contains only 32 or less variables.

[image]

If I look at the initial correlation matrix then I do not find anything special about the last 4 variables. Correlation coefficients between those variables and other variables in the matrix are in the range from $-.49$ and $.79$.

Anyway, does my finding of exponentially growing diagonal elements of inverse matrices indicate any porblem with my data? Or may this all just point to issues such as rounding errors `R` is doing when computing the inverse of a relatively large matrix?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the usual methods of figuring out how many factors there are? (e.g. proportion of variance explained, eigenvalues over 1, scree test or substantive meaning)?

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica, in general simualtion studies suggest that parallel analsyis (as well as revised parallel analsyis) outperform the more traditional methods of dimensionality assessment in terms of accuracy.